# Do these sorts of submonoids go by a particular name?

Tags: semigroups-and-monoids

Given any monoid $M$ for every element $x\in M$ we can define two submonoids of $M$ as follows:
$$r(x)=\{y\in M:xy=x\}$$
$$l(x)=\{y\in M:yx=x\}$$

Do these sorts of sub-monoids go by a particular name?

Comment: The tag (abstract-algebra) is deprecated on MathOverflow, see [the tag-info](https://mathoverflow.net/tags/abstract-algebra/info). (And the question is also [missing top-level tag](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1457/why-are-mo-tags-formatted-as-they-are).) Perhaps somebody might have suggestion which tags might be suitable here.

Answer (score 2):

If $M$ acts on a set $X$ on the right, and $x\in X$, then $r(x)=\{y\in M\;|\;xy=x\}$ is the right stabilizer of $x$. You can find $r(x)$ referred to this way in, for example,

Theory of Codes
Berstel and Perrin
Academic Press, 1985
Page 95

or

Semigroups with idempotent stabilizers
and applications to automata theory.
Bertrand Le Saec, Jean-Eric Pin and Pascal Weil
International Journal of Algebra and Computation, 1991, 1, pp.291-314.
Page 1

You are interested in only two particular actions, the left and right actions of $M$ on itself, but it would be reasonable to refer to $r(x)$ the right stabilizer of $x$ and $\ell(x)$ the left stabilizer of $x$ even in this restricted setting.

Comment: Is there literature about bands (semigroups which have these relations as identities) which would talk about these sets in things that are not bands?  Gerhard "Looking For The Binding Tie" Paseman, 2018.11.24.

Comment: This terminology is used everywhere in semigroup theory. For an older book reference see Page 358 of Eilenberg's Automata, Languages and Machines Vol. B 1976.